# RegEx performance optimisation

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that strips away the boolean conditions from a string. I performed some benchmarking, and I noticed that running this regex replace on a string, 1000 times, took between 5-11 seconds. I'm pretty new to regex performance, but this seemed a slow.

Here is the regex:`"\bAND\b|\bOR\b|""|\(|\)"`

Is this performance expected, or could I re-write my regex to improve the performace. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Benchmark code:

```
Regex booleanRegex = new Regex(@"\bAND\b|\bOR\b|""|\(|\)", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |   RegexOptions.Compiled);
Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
var inputString = "AND project manager";
t.Start();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   booleanRegex.Replace(inputString,"");
}
t.Stop();
var regex = t.ElapsedMilliseconds;

regex.Dump();
```

Comment: Compiling it before usage might help a bit. Also it depends on how big the string is

Comment: Please show your benchmarking code. Either your benchmarking is wrong, or the text on which you run it is extremely long.

Comment: Did you run your benchmark multiple times ? There might be some JIT delay going on.

Comment: Just ran the posted benchmark code in LINQPad. Runs in < 10 ms on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this but i am not sure that it makes a big difference:

```
[""()]|\b(?>AND|OR)\b
```

Here I assume that "() are more frequent than AND and OR. I use parenthesis to avoid to evaluate the `\b` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use  `RegexOptions.Compiled` ? If not, that should give you a speed up. Just make sure you only initialize the Regex object once.